# IBM DB2 TextSearch // Language = AUTO // Linguistic processing

Tags: database, db2, full-text-search, tokenize

I am using the latest release of the IBM DB2 Express-C edition LUW on Windows Server 32Bit.

The TextSearch-Engine is properly configured and working so far.

I created a small test table with a primary key id-column an a varchar column. The varchar column is defined as a fulltext index.

```
db2ts "CREATE INDEX db2admin.test_id_dx FOR TEXT ON test(anytext) LANGUAGE AUTO CONNECT TO M2FDEVTS USER xxx USING yyy"
```

As you can see I set the language parameter to AUTO.

Checking the index configuration with

```
SELECT * FROM sysibmts.tsindexes
```

the column "language" is set to AUTO.

Just to be safe I set the global configuration to AUTO as well. I checked it with

```
SELECT * FROM sysibmts.TSDEFAULTS
```

**My question:**

I can not determine which language a text has when it is put into the table. So I inserted rows with german and english content. The content was not mixed within a row.

After updating the index I made some queries.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(anytext,1,30)  FROM test WHERE CONTAINS(anytext, 'spiele', 'QUERYLANGUAGE = de_DE') = 1
```

First of all I created the index with language mode = auto. The word "spiele" was not part of any text in the fulltext-column. But thinking of the linguistic processing of the db2 fulltext index, there should have been some hits. But no result at all.

After that I dropped the index and recreated it with language de_DE. After updating the index I fired the same query again - now returning some result rows!

So what´s wrong? There is obviously a difference between creating an Index with language=auto and language=de_DE. I´ve studied the documentation. It clearly says:

> The locale that you specify in yourdb2ts CREATE INDEXcommand determines
>   the language used to tokenize or analyze documents for indexing. If you know
>   that all documents in the column to be indexed use a specific language, specify
>   the applicable locale when you create the text search index. If you do not specify
>   a locale, the database territory will be used to determine the default setting for
>   LANGUAGE. To have your documents automatically scanned to determine the
>   locale, in the SYSIBMTS.TSDEFAULTS view, set the LANGUAGEattribute toAUTO.
>   The SYSIBMTS.TSDEFAULTS view describes database defaults for text search
>   using attribute-value pairs.

Thank you very much for your help!
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the solutions is quite easy. The sentences I used for testing where too short. In this case DB2 was not able to determine which language to choose for tokenisation.

Creating an index, based on the correct language or using sentences with more words, the query results are as expected.

Oliver